# How to Determine Trial License in Debug and Release Mode

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Basically my question is, when testing out an application on a physical device in Windows Phone 7, in release mode, will a trial license be set as 'false'? I have read that in Window Phone 8 in release mode the trial license will be either `missing` or `revoked`. I am trying to test an old WP7' application's trial mode from referencing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286402(v=vs.105).aspx but when placing a breakpoint over the `IsTrial` when in release mode it returns a 'false'. I just though this was curious, but wanted to be sure that when updating my app in the marketplace the 'LicenseInformation' class would be returning the proper value of the trial license (my first launch had a small bug I had to fix regarding trial implementation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's "normal" that IsTrial always return false, that's why they hardcode the value in Debug mode so that you can test both case. You can find confirmation [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/creating-a-windows-phone-7-trial-application-implementation-and-best-practices) for example:

> If you are running the application while developing (in the emulator),
>   then IsTrial() will always return FALSE

For windows phone 8 there is a new [LicenseInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.aspx) class (in a different namespace) which behave a little differently but the previous class from windows phone 7 is still available and still work the same.

Comment: Thanks, I am using the new version in a Windows Phone 8 app as well, but I was having trouble with both working. Maybe you could shoot over to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528356/why-could-my-application-trial-not-be-working-in-the-marketplace and check it out?