# Why Could My Application Trial Not be Working in the Marketplace

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, operators

I recently have released a small application with a trial to the Windows Phone Marketplace, but my application is not working as expected. I have followed http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Trial-Experience-Sample-c58f21af when making my trial, so that I can call the current 'LicenseInformation' state and block a feature or not depending on the current application's license state. According to the sample application, `The LicenseMode property returns a value from the LicenseModes enum (Full, MissingOrRevoked, or Trial) so that your app code needs to check only a single value. There’s also a convenient Boolean IsFull property. Whenever the license mode has changed, or it is likely to have changed, TrialExperienceHelper raises its LicenseChanged event and your app code can handle that event to query LicenseMode or IsFull again. Then, your app can control the availability of features, ads, and your Buy UI as needed.`

In my application I have a click event in which I would like to perform an action based on the current LicenseInformation state and upon a count (the count being the number of times an image is saved with particular aspects applied).

`Settings.SavedCount.Value` records the number of times the save button is clicked, and if the count is above 100 and the application is in trial mode I would like to ask the user if they would like to upgrade, otherwise if the count is less than 100 while the application is in trial mode or if the license is in full mode then the user is allowed to continue with the save process (hopefully that makes logical sense).

```
void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings.SavedCount.Value += 1;        

    if (TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Trial" && Settings.SavedCount.Value > 100)
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("You have saved over 100 items! Would you like to continue?", "Congratulations!", MeesageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        switch (result)
        {
            case MessageBoxResult.OK:
                //A command takes a parameter so pass null
                TrialViewModel.BuyCommand.Execute(null);
                break;
            case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                editPagePivotControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
                break;                  
        }
    }
    else if ((TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Trial" && Settings.SavedCount.Value <= 100) || (TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Full")
        {
            PerformSaveAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

When testing in Debug mode and with the sample implementation from the msdn website, the Trial and Full implementations worked properly, and then when in Release mode the license was listed as MissingOrRevoked which I assumed would be called correctly in the marketplace. What is ACTUALLY occuring when i have downloaded the app in the marketplace under both trial and full modes is that the `PerformSaveAsync()` method is never being called (which ultimately saves the new image and disables the button) and I can use the new image elsewhere. I am having trouble figuring out what the issue may be?

EDIT** In researching I came across http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691310(v=vs.71).aspx which states that `The operation x && y corresponds to the operation x & y, except that y is evaluated only if x is true.` and `•The operation x || y corresponds to the operation x | y, except that y is evaluated only if x is false/' . Would this be the cause of the issues? If so, how should they be fixed?

Edit 2** Addtion of TrialViewModel and TrialExperienceHelper.cs for additional info

TrialViewModel

```
TrialViewModel

#region fields
private RelayCommand buyCommand;
#endregion fields

#region constructors
public TrialViewModel()
{
    // Subscribe to the helper class's static LicenseChanged event so that we can re-query its LicenseMode property when it changes.
    TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseChanged += TrialExperienceHelper_LicenseChanged;
}
#endregion constructors

#region properties        
/// <summary>
/// You can bind the Command property of a Button to BuyCommand. When the Button is clicked, BuyCommand will be
/// invoked. The Button will be enabled as long as BuyCommand can execute.
/// </summary>
public RelayCommand BuyCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (this.buyCommand == null)
        {
            // The RelayCommand is constructed with two parameters - the action to perform on invocation,
            // and the condition under which the command can execute. It's important to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged
            // on a command whenever its can-execute condition might have changed. Here, we do that in the TrialExperienceHelper_LicenseChanged
            // event handler.
            this.buyCommand = new RelayCommand(
                param => TrialExperienceHelper.Buy(),
                param => TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode == TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseModes.Trial);
        }
        return this.buyCommand;
    }
}

public string LicenseModeString
{
    get
    {
        return TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode.ToString()/* + ' ' + AppResources.ModeString*/;
    }
}
#endregion properties

#region event handlers
// Handle TrialExperienceHelper's LicenseChanged event by raising property changed notifications on the
// properties and commands that 
internal void TrialExperienceHelper_LicenseChanged()
{
    this.RaisePropertyChanged("LicenseModeString");
    this.BuyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
#endregion event handlers
```

TrialExperienceHelper.cs

```
#region enums
    /// <summary>
    /// The LicenseModes enumeration describes the mode of a license.
    /// </summary>
    public enum LicenseModes
    {
        Full,
        MissingOrRevoked,
        Trial
    }
    #endregion enums

    #region fields
#if DEBUG
    // Determines how a debug build behaves on launch. This field is set to LicenseModes.Full after simulating a purchase.
    // Calling the Buy method (or navigating away from the app and back) will simulate a purchase.
    internal static LicenseModes simulatedLicMode = LicenseModes.Trial;
#endif // DEBUG
    private static bool isActiveCache;
    private static bool isTrialCache;
    #endregion fields

    #region constructors
    // The static constructor effectively initializes the cache of the state of the license when the app is launched. It also attaches
    // a handler so that we can refresh the cache whenever the license has (potentially) changed.
    static TrialExperienceHelper()
    {
        TrialExperienceHelper.RefreshCache();
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.Activated += (object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e) => TrialExperienceHelper.
#if DEBUG
            // In debug configuration, when the user returns to the application we will simulate a purchase.
OnSimulatedPurchase();
#else // DEBUG
            // In release configuration, when the user returns to the application we will refresh the cache.
RefreshCache();
#endif // DEBUG
    }
    #endregion constructors

    #region properties
    /// <summary>
    /// The LicenseMode property combines the active and trial states of the license into a single
    /// enumerated value. In debug configuration, the simulated value is returned. In release configuration,
    /// if the license is active then it is either trial or full. If the license is not active then
    /// it is either missing or revoked.
    /// </summary>
    public static LicenseModes LicenseMode
    {
        get
        {
#if DEBUG
            return simulatedLicMode;
#else // DEBUG
            if (TrialExperienceHelper.isActiveCache)
            {
                return TrialExperienceHelper.isTrialCache ? LicenseModes.Trial : LicenseModes.Full;
            }
            else // License is inactive.
            {
                return LicenseModes.MissingOrRevoked;
            }
#endif // DEBUG
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The IsFull property provides a convenient way of checking whether the license is full or not.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsFull
    {
        get
        {
            return (TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode == LicenseModes.Full);
        }
    }
    #endregion properties

    #region methods
    /// <summary>
    /// The Buy method can be called when the license state is trial. the user is given the opportunity
    /// to buy the app after which, in all configurations, the Activated event is raised, which we handle.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Buy()
    {
        MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
        marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
        marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method can be called at any time to refresh the values stored in the cache. We re-query the application object
    /// for the current state of the license and cache the fresh values. We also raise the LicenseChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RefreshCache()
    {
        TrialExperienceHelper.isActiveCache = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.IsActive;
        TrialExperienceHelper.isTrialCache = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.IsTrial;
        TrialExperienceHelper.RaiseLicenseChanged();
    }

    private static void RaiseLicenseChanged()
    {
        if (TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseChanged != null)
        {
            TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseChanged();
        }
    }

#if DEBUG
    private static void OnSimulatedPurchase()
    {
        TrialExperienceHelper.simulatedLicMode = LicenseModes.Full;
        TrialExperienceHelper.RaiseLicenseChanged();
    }
#endif // DEBUG
    #endregion methods

    #region events
    /// <summary>
    /// The static LicenseChanged event is raised whenever the value of the LicenseMode property has (potentially) changed.
    /// </summary>
    public static event LicenseChangedEventHandler LicenseChanged;
    #endregion events
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dev builds work and the only difference is with the app being published via the store then I think it's very unlikely to be your logic.

When you submitted the app, are you sure you checked the option to be able to use the trial functionality in the app?

[image: free trial option partial screenshot]

If you didn't check this then it won't work in a released app.

Comment: Yes, I believe I did because a trial or purchase version is offered in the store (although I unpublished the app from the store upon finding these errors so nobody else would go through the same situation).

Comment: Do you think it could be the conditional operators not executing both conditional statements within the `if else`? Reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691310(v=vs.71).aspx made me think twice about whether I should use logical or conditional operators. Also, I was considering performing a different string comparison method and posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530857/trouble-with-logical-and-conditional-operators/19538644?noredirect=1#19538644 . What are your thoughts?

Comment: Ok, it seems I have no choice but to try and update the application in the marketplace. I did check and I do have the Trial option checked along with offering the application at the base price tier (.99$ USD) in all markets. If this isn't it, I'm going to change the order of checking items in my if statement as well as possibly using logical operators instead of conditional. If its not this then I'm not sure what, possibly reverting back to the WP7 way of checking trial licenses.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your edit, I don't see any problem with your condition, your quote is just that the operator is lazy, evaluating only what is needed to determine the result (for example when you do x&& y if x is false,  x&& false=> false and x&& true==false which is the same result so it don't evaluate y).
 Also like I said in your previous question even the windows phone 7 api still work on windows phone 8 so if you are creating code for both platform there is probably no need to use the new api specifically for wp8.
In this code I don't see any problem but why do you convert the LicenseModes enum to string, using the enum will add some type safety and prevent you to do some invalid comparison.
The only problem is where you set  LicenseModeString  or a problem inside PerformSaveAsync?

Comment: I must have misworded myself about the LicenseModes enum, it is `public enum LicenseModes
        {
            Full,
            MissingOrRevoked,
            Trial
        }`. I believe I am going to change the order of my conditions to check `Settings.SavedCount.Value` before checking `TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString`. Also should I change to logical instead of conditional operators to check the entire if else statements? And `PerformSaveAsync` isn't being called yet at all because it updates the view and disables a button so I would see that change.

Comment: In additional, i'm going to update my solution to compare TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString with its states of either Trial or Full using another string comparison version as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165449(v=vs.110).aspx which may help? At this point I'll try anything.

Comment: @Matthew Like I said in my response, I don't think changing the order will change anything, whatever the order the response is still the same, it's just some part will not get evaluated to save some time (what you would like). The only thing you need to make sure is that you have the parentheses at the right place, which seem to be good in the code you pasted (even though on the second if there is a missing parentheses at the end but I guess it's just a bad copy paste. Also I still don't understand why you don't keep the LicenseModes enum value in your TrialViewModel instead of a string ...

Comment: Your right, it was a copy and paste error and I dont think the order will change anything either honestly. I did however add my TrialViewModel and TrialExperienceHelper as an edit so you can see what exactly I am doing with determing `TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString`. `LicenseMode` is called in `TrialExperienceHelper.cs` which should return the license state, but maybe `isActiveCache` is False which shouldn't happen when the applicatin is downloaded from the Marketplace correct?

Comment: IsActive is set to false only after expiration if you set some time based expiration in the store otherwise it should always be true. I see in your get that you have a commented part with some additional text, if you are planning to uncomment that at some point it will break the condition, that's why it would be better to create another property which just return TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode to be sure that you are comparing to the right thing ...

Comment: Well, I did not know that there was an available option to expire an application when it is in the Marketplace, I'm going to have to look into this and possibly contact respective Microsoft dev support on the issue if I have no other option. And in the get I was going to just remove that commented code it was left in there on accident.