# Trouble with Logical and Conditional Operators

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I am having trouble figuring out the proper implementation using logical/conditional operators. I have a very specific requirement for an application and I thought at first it was working correctly, but when placed on the Marketplace I come to find out my implementation is not working at all.

1. If my application is in trial mode and the count of saved occurrences is > 100 the I need to perform an action.
2. If the application is in Trial mode and the count of saved occurrences is <= 100, or the application is in full mode then I need to perform another action.

What I have is as follows in a button click event

```
//recorded count of number of saved button presses
Settings.SavedCount.Value += 1;
        //both conditions must be true for the code to execute inside the 'if'
        if (TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString ==  "Trial" && Settings.SavedCount.Value > 100)
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("You have saved over 100 items! Would you like to continue?", "Congratulations", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            switch (result)
            {
                case MessageBoxResult.OK:
                    // A command takes a parameter and in this case we can pass null.
                    TrialViewModel.BuyCommand.Execute(null);
                    break;
                case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                    return;
                    break;
            }
        }
        //either the entire first condition OR the second condition must be true to execute the method ApplyAndSaveAsync()
        else if((TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Trial" && Settings.SavedCount.Value <= 100) || TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Full")
        {
            ApplyAndSaveAsync();
        }
```

when debugging everything seemed to work fine, although when I tested the application once it was downloaded from the marketplace in both trial and full modes, in neither case did `ApplyAndSaveAsync()` execute. To note, the count will always increase indefinitely but the application may or may not be in Trial mode. It is only in Trial mode if it is downloaded as a trial and before a user updates it, in which case its license will automatically change to Full mode.

EDIT**

Possible use of ordinal string comparison instead of '==" as stated in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165449(v=vs.110).aspx .

```
string _license = TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString;
string _isTrial = "Trial";

// Use the overload of the Equals method that specifies a StringComparison. 
// Ordinal is the fastest way to compare two strings.
bool result = _license.Equals(_isTrial, StringComparison.Ordinal);

Settings.SavedCount.Value += 1;
//both conditions must be true for the code to execute inside the 'if'
    if (result && Settings.SavedCount.Value > 100)
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("You have saved over 100 items! Would you like to continue?", "Congratulations", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        switch (result)
        {
            case MessageBoxResult.OK:
                // A command takes a parameter and in this case we can pass null.
                TrialViewModel.BuyCommand.Execute(null);
                break;
            case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                return;
                break;
        }
    }
    //either the entire first condition OR the second condition must be true to execute the method ApplyAndSaveAsync()
    else if((result && Settings.SavedCount.Value <= 100) || TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Full")
    {
        ApplyAndSaveAsync();
    }
```

Also, what would be the difference between using logical and conditional AND and OR functions? I want to be sure that both statements in the `if` and `if else` statements are evaluated to ensure proper procedure. Is my implementation correct for this?

Edit 2** Addition of View Model and Class helper for Trial Implementation

TrialViewModel

```
#region fields
private RelayCommand buyCommand;
#endregion fields

#region constructors
public TrialViewModel()
{
    // Subscribe to the helper class's static LicenseChanged event so that we can re-query its LicenseMode property when it changes.
    TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseChanged += TrialExperienceHelper_LicenseChanged;
}
#endregion constructors

#region properties        
/// <summary>
/// You can bind the Command property of a Button to BuyCommand. When the Button is clicked, BuyCommand will be
/// invoked. The Button will be enabled as long as BuyCommand can execute.
/// </summary>
public RelayCommand BuyCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (this.buyCommand == null)
        {
            // The RelayCommand is constructed with two parameters - the action to perform on invocation,
            // and the condition under which the command can execute. It's important to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged
            // on a command whenever its can-execute condition might have changed. Here, we do that in the TrialExperienceHelper_LicenseChanged
            // event handler.
            this.buyCommand = new RelayCommand(
                param => TrialExperienceHelper.Buy(),
                param => TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode == TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseModes.Trial);
        }
        return this.buyCommand;
    }
}

public string LicenseModeString
{
    get
    {
        return TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode.ToString()/* + ' ' + AppResources.ModeString*/;
    }
}
#endregion properties

#region event handlers
// Handle TrialExperienceHelper's LicenseChanged event by raising property changed notifications on the
// properties and commands that 
internal void TrialExperienceHelper_LicenseChanged()
{
    this.RaisePropertyChanged("LicenseModeString");
    this.BuyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
#endregion event handlers
```

TrialExperienceHelper.cs

```
#region enums
    /// <summary>
    /// The LicenseModes enumeration describes the mode of a license.
    /// </summary>
    public enum LicenseModes
    {
        Full,
        MissingOrRevoked,
        Trial
    }
    #endregion enums

    #region fields
#if DEBUG
    // Determines how a debug build behaves on launch. This field is set to LicenseModes.Full after simulating a purchase.
    // Calling the Buy method (or navigating away from the app and back) will simulate a purchase.
    internal static LicenseModes simulatedLicMode = LicenseModes.Trial;
#endif // DEBUG
    private static bool isActiveCache;
    private static bool isTrialCache;
    #endregion fields

    #region constructors
    // The static constructor effectively initializes the cache of the state of the license when the app is launched. It also attaches
    // a handler so that we can refresh the cache whenever the license has (potentially) changed.
    static TrialExperienceHelper()
    {
        TrialExperienceHelper.RefreshCache();
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.Activated += (object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e) => TrialExperienceHelper.
#if DEBUG
            // In debug configuration, when the user returns to the application we will simulate a purchase.
OnSimulatedPurchase();
#else // DEBUG
            // In release configuration, when the user returns to the application we will refresh the cache.
RefreshCache();
#endif // DEBUG
    }
    #endregion constructors

    #region properties
    /// <summary>
    /// The LicenseMode property combines the active and trial states of the license into a single
    /// enumerated value. In debug configuration, the simulated value is returned. In release configuration,
    /// if the license is active then it is either trial or full. If the license is not active then
    /// it is either missing or revoked.
    /// </summary>
    public static LicenseModes LicenseMode
    {
        get
        {
#if DEBUG
            return simulatedLicMode;
#else // DEBUG
            if (TrialExperienceHelper.isActiveCache)
            {
                return TrialExperienceHelper.isTrialCache ? LicenseModes.Trial : LicenseModes.Full;
            }
            else // License is inactive.
            {
                return LicenseModes.MissingOrRevoked;
            }
#endif // DEBUG
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The IsFull property provides a convenient way of checking whether the license is full or not.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsFull
    {
        get
        {
            return (TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode == LicenseModes.Full);
        }
    }
    #endregion properties

    #region methods
    /// <summary>
    /// The Buy method can be called when the license state is trial. the user is given the opportunity
    /// to buy the app after which, in all configurations, the Activated event is raised, which we handle.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Buy()
    {
        MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
        marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
        marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method can be called at any time to refresh the values stored in the cache. We re-query the application object
    /// for the current state of the license and cache the fresh values. We also raise the LicenseChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RefreshCache()
    {
        TrialExperienceHelper.isActiveCache = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.IsActive;
        TrialExperienceHelper.isTrialCache = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.IsTrial;
        TrialExperienceHelper.RaiseLicenseChanged();
    }

    private static void RaiseLicenseChanged()
    {
        if (TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseChanged != null)
        {
            TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseChanged();
        }
    }

#if DEBUG
    private static void OnSimulatedPurchase()
    {
        TrialExperienceHelper.simulatedLicMode = LicenseModes.Full;
        TrialExperienceHelper.RaiseLicenseChanged();
    }
#endif // DEBUG
    #endregion methods

    #region events
    /// <summary>
    /// The static LicenseChanged event is raised whenever the value of the LicenseMode property has (potentially) changed.
    /// </summary>
    public static event LicenseChangedEventHandler LicenseChanged;
    #endregion events
```

Comment: Your conditional operators are fine. The problem probably comes from the actual value of `TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString` in the published app

Comment: OK, I followed http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Trial-Experience-Sample-c58f21af#content tutorial in my app, and the values matched correctly when debugging and so forth. I have no way of determining what the values are though after downloading from the marketplace for testing which is when the unexpected behavior occurs.

Comment: Can you produce a minimal example which reproduces the issue? Also, have you tried creating a beta app in the store to see if that reproduces it or is it just down to the "proper" release version of the app?

Comment: Yes I will definitely create a sample of my implementation and I can post it on my SkyDrive later today (this evening I'm in EST time). I havent created a beta because I read on an MSDN article that the trial wouldn't be able to be detected for some reason, not sure why. I am adding my `TrialViewModel` and `TrialExperienceHelper` as an edit above. I think the issue may be `isActiveCache` is returning False and therefore `LicenseModeString` is `MissingOrRevoked` in the Marketplace. In this case nothing in my method (above) will be executed (which is what happens when testing in Release mode).

Comment: Also I posted another question thinking it oculd be an issue of my operators not working correctly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557180/difference-between-conditional-and-logical-operator-evaluation/19558010?noredirect=1#comment29023977_19558010 and I am now using logical instead of conditional operators. Another part of my solution which I recently discovered that uses conditional operators is not working as expected either (which has nothing to do with the trial, just `&&` and `||` operators. I will include this as well in my sample I create later.

Comment: @MattLacey how might I send you a sample project of my reproduced error? email?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a show in the dark, but in some cases (somtimes in Java, but I am not sure about .NET) string comparison with "==" does not work. You could try using the "compare" method instead of "==".

Comment: I think you are on to something. I added an edit to my solution above using a string comparison as referenced by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165449(v=vs.110).aspx . I want to be sure though that this will work when the application is using another culture/language. The `TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString` enums are hard coded in a class to be (Trial, Full, or MissingOrRevoked) so I dont believe this would be an issue. What would you suggest?

Comment: Also, I really think it may have sometihng to do with the `&&` and `||` operators and how they are evauluated, but I'm not sure what the proper implementation will be. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691310(v=vs.71).aspx the order of the statements before and after the operators and their values of true or false determine how the endtire conditional statement is executed. Should I be using logical operators instead? I really need everthing in the if else statements to be evaluated before the resulting code is executed.