# Difference Between Conditional and Logical Operator Evaluation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, operators, logic

I am having trouble figuring out the proper implementation of an if else statement in my application. Currently I am using the conditional operators `&&` and `||` for comparison, but when my application is launched in the marketplace my code is not operating as planned. Essentially the way it should work is that if the count is greater than 100 and the application is still a trial license then ask to upgrade, otherwise if the count is less than or equal to 100 and the application is still a trial license OR the application is a full license then allow ApplyAndSaveAsync method to execute.

```
Settings.SavedCount.Value += 1;
        if ((Settings.SavedCount.Value > 100) && (TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Trial"))
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("You have saved over 100 items! Would you like to continue?", "Congratulations", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            switch (result)
            {
                case MessageBoxResult.OK:
                    // A command takes a parameter and in this case we can pass null.
                    TrialViewModel.BuyCommand.Execute(null);
                    break;
                case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                    return;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (((Settings.SavedCount.Value <= 100) && (TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Trial")) || (TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Full"))
        {
            ApplyAndSaveAsync();
        }
```

To note, `TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString` can either be `Trial` or `Full` in the string comparison and it seems to be working properly. `Settings.SavedCount.Value` is also incrementing properly as well. `TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString` is queries the license state which is automatically set in the application whether the user downloads a trial or full version, or when a user upgrades a trial to the full version, so I do not think this is the issue. For some reason though when testing my app in both Trial and Full states from the Marketplace, the `ApplyAndSaveAsync` method never executes?

I have tried reversing the check of `TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString` and `Settings.Saved.Count.Value` so the count will be checked first, but I'm not sure if this would help. I referenced http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691310(v=vs.71).aspx which states that `The operation x && y corresponds to the operation x & y, except that y is evaluated only if x is true. The operation x || y corresponds to the operation x | y, except that y is evaluated only if x is false.` So I am not sure if my statement below will work appropriately?

```
Settings.SavedCount.Value += 1;
        if ((Settings.SavedCount.Value > 100) && (TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Trial"))
        {
            //MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("You have saved over 100 filtered pictures! Would you like to continue?", "Congratulations", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(AppResources.EditPage_MessageBoxContent_Purchase, AppResources.EditPage_MessageBoxCaption_Purchase, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            switch (result)
            {
                case MessageBoxResult.OK:
                    // A command takes a parameter and in this case we can pass null.
                    TrialViewModel.BuyCommand.Execute(null);
                    break;
                case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                    if (editPagePivotControl != null && editPagePivotControl.SelectedIndex != 0)
                    {
                        //trialPopup.IsOpen = false;
                        editPagePivotControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (((Settings.SavedCount.Value <= 100) && (TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Trial")) || (TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Full"))
        {
            ApplySelectedEffectAndSaveAsync();
        }
```

And my final question is should I use a single `&` and `|` operators instead?

```
Settings.SavedCount.Value += 1;
        if ((Settings.SavedCount.Value > 1) & (TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Trial"))
        {
            //MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("You have saved over 100 filtered pictures! Would you like to continue?", "Congratulations", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(AppResources.EditPage_MessageBoxContent_Purchase, AppResources.EditPage_MessageBoxCaption_Purchase, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            switch (result)
            {
                case MessageBoxResult.OK:
                    // A command takes a parameter and in this case we can pass null.
                    TrialViewModel.BuyCommand.Execute(null);
                    break;
                case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                    if (editPagePivotControl != null && editPagePivotControl.SelectedIndex != 0)
                    {
                        //trialPopup.IsOpen = false;
                        editPagePivotControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (((Settings.SavedCount.Value <= 1) & (TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Trial")) | (TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString == "Full"))
        {
            ApplySelectedEffectAndSaveAsync();
        }
```

TrialViewModel

```
#region fields
    private RelayCommand buyCommand;
    #endregion fields

    #region constructors
    public TrialViewModel()
    {
        // Subscribe to the helper class's static LicenseChanged event so that we can re-query its LicenseMode property when it changes.
        TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseChanged += TrialExperienceHelper_LicenseChanged;
    }
    #endregion constructors

    #region properties        
    /// <summary>
    /// You can bind the Command property of a Button to BuyCommand. When the Button is clicked, BuyCommand will be
    /// invoked. The Button will be enabled as long as BuyCommand can execute.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand BuyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.buyCommand == null)
            {
                // The RelayCommand is constructed with two parameters - the action to perform on invocation,
                // and the condition under which the command can execute. It's important to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged
                // on a command whenever its can-execute condition might have changed. Here, we do that in the TrialExperienceHelper_LicenseChanged
                // event handler.
                this.buyCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    param => TrialExperienceHelper.Buy(),
                    param => TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode == TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseModes.Trial);
            }
            return this.buyCommand;
        }
    }

    public string LicenseModeString
    {
        get
        {
            return TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode.ToString()/* + ' ' + AppResources.ModeString*/;
        }
    }
    #endregion properties

    #region event handlers
    // Handle TrialExperienceHelper's LicenseChanged event by raising property changed notifications on the
    // properties and commands that 
    internal void TrialExperienceHelper_LicenseChanged()
    {
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("LicenseModeString");
        this.BuyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
    #endregion event handlers
```

TrialExperienceHelper.cs

```
#region enums
    /// <summary>
    /// The LicenseModes enumeration describes the mode of a license.
    /// </summary>
    public enum LicenseModes
    {
        Full,
        MissingOrRevoked,
        Trial
    }
    #endregion enums

    #region fields
#if DEBUG
    // Determines how a debug build behaves on launch. This field is set to LicenseModes.Full after simulating a purchase.
    // Calling the Buy method (or navigating away from the app and back) will simulate a purchase.
    internal static LicenseModes simulatedLicMode = LicenseModes.Trial;
#endif // DEBUG
    private static bool isActiveCache;
    private static bool isTrialCache;
    #endregion fields

    #region constructors
    // The static constructor effectively initializes the cache of the state of the license when the app is launched. It also attaches
    // a handler so that we can refresh the cache whenever the license has (potentially) changed.
    static TrialExperienceHelper()
    {
        TrialExperienceHelper.RefreshCache();
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.Activated += (object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e) => TrialExperienceHelper.
#if DEBUG
            // In debug configuration, when the user returns to the application we will simulate a purchase.
```

OnSimulatedPurchase();
    #else // DEBUG
                // In release configuration, when the user returns to the application we will refresh the cache.
RefreshCache();
    #endif // DEBUG
        }
        #endregion constructors

```
    #region properties
    /// <summary>
    /// The LicenseMode property combines the active and trial states of the license into a single
    /// enumerated value. In debug configuration, the simulated value is returned. In release configuration,
    /// if the license is active then it is either trial or full. If the license is not active then
    /// it is either missing or revoked.
    /// </summary>
    public static LicenseModes LicenseMode
    {
        get
        {
#if DEBUG
            return simulatedLicMode;
#else // DEBUG
            if (TrialExperienceHelper.isActiveCache)
            {
                return TrialExperienceHelper.isTrialCache ? LicenseModes.Trial : LicenseModes.Full;
            }
            else // License is inactive.
            {
                return LicenseModes.MissingOrRevoked;
            }
#endif // DEBUG
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The IsFull property provides a convenient way of checking whether the license is full or not.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsFull
    {
        get
        {
            return (TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode == LicenseModes.Full);
        }
    }
    #endregion properties

    #region methods
    /// <summary>
    /// The Buy method can be called when the license state is trial. the user is given the opportunity
    /// to buy the app after which, in all configurations, the Activated event is raised, which we handle.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Buy()
    {
        MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
        marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
        marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method can be called at any time to refresh the values stored in the cache. We re-query the application object
    /// for the current state of the license and cache the fresh values. We also raise the LicenseChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RefreshCache()
    {
        TrialExperienceHelper.isActiveCache = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.IsActive;
        TrialExperienceHelper.isTrialCache = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.IsTrial;
        TrialExperienceHelper.RaiseLicenseChanged();
    }

    private static void RaiseLicenseChanged()
    {
        if (TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseChanged != null)
        {
            TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseChanged();
        }
    }

#if DEBUG
    private static void OnSimulatedPurchase()
    {
        TrialExperienceHelper.simulatedLicMode = LicenseModes.Full;
        TrialExperienceHelper.RaiseLicenseChanged();
    }
#endif // DEBUG
    #endregion methods

    #region events
    /// <summary>
    /// The static LicenseChanged event is raised whenever the value of the LicenseMode property has (potentially) changed.
    /// </summary>
    public static event LicenseChangedEventHandler LicenseChanged;
    #endregion events
```

Answer (score 0):

You logic seems ok. Are you sure `TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString` returns exactly `Trial` or `Full`?

By the way, in your case it makes no difference whether you use the `&&` or `&` operator. It does make a difference when one part of the logical expression is a method. For instance:

```
int i = 0;
if ((i >= 100) & (a.IncreaseCounter() > 5))
  // a.IncreaseCounter() will be executed even while i is less than 100

if ((i >= 100) && (a.IncreaseCounter() > 5))
  // a.IncreaseCounter() will not be excuted
```

The first `if` statement first evaluates both sides of the expression and then checks if the expression is true or false. The second statement short circuits the evaluation.  Because the left epression is false it does not evaluate the right side because it already knows the end result will be false.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I added `TrialViewModel` which uses `TrialExperienceHelper.cs` to determine the current app license state. Maybe you can see something I'm overlooking? And do you mean my logic in the first original method seems ok? I did notice that in another part of my application my conditional statements using `&&` and `||` did not work as expected either although when debugging everything seemed ok. Weird I know. So now I am using the single `&` and `|` operators to see if this will make a difference when my application is on the marketplace.

Comment: To note, when referencing http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Trial-Experience-Sample-c58f21af#content it gives a really good description on how the trial implementation works and what `TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString` returns. In Debug mode in Visual Studio, it will return either `Trial` or `Full` to mimic the real license state, but in Release mode it returns `MissingOrRevoked` because there is no real license state to query. This is solved however once the application is on the marketplace and a license can be determined.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are publishing the Release version of your app?

Comment: In just thinking about the value of `TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString` in release mode when a license state of `MissingOrRevoked` occurs, all conditions are skipped and nothing happens within the method. I have no way of knowing the values once the app is downloaded and ran on my device from the marketplace, but visually the exact same behavior is occurring.

Comment: Yes yes, I must have been writing my previous comment as you sent yours.

Comment: Sorry, I'm clueless. It seems like `isActiveCache` is false and therefore `TrialViewModel.LicenseModeString` returns `MissingOrRevoked`. Why `isActiveCache` returns false is unclear to me.